# How to trigger upload event for Uploader control?

Tags: speak

I am adding a Speak UI launchpad application to allow content editors to upload a CSV file that contains data they need to update periodically. Currently, it's an error-prone manual process and this can hopefully make things easier.

I've added a Speak-TaskPage item to the YourApps node in the core database. And I added Uploader, Uploader Info, and Button controls to the layout. 
I set the database and destination URL (to a location in the media library) to the Uploader control. 
I set the click event to "upload" to the Button control.

[This](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/uploader) says "The Uploader control provides users with a way to select files and a member function to upload selected files. You can raise the upload event from a button to trigger this function. Users can then upload selected files by clicking the button." and implies to me that I only need to set the click event to "upload" for it to work.

After doing all this, I can see my application page, I can select a document to upload, but after clicking the upload button, nothing happens. There is no activity in the network section of the developer console in the browser. I do see that the button control is not contained within the  section of the uploader control. Is it supposed to be this way? If not, how can I move the button control inside it? I couldn't figure out how.

[image: Layout]

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the problem.
In the UploadButton rendering, the click event needs to be set to "javascript:app.Uploader.viewModel.upload()" (where "Uploader" is the ID of the uploader rendering). I had only entered "upload" in this field.